Systemd instance units with dynamic parameters
I have a server that continuously deploys new version of the application.
systemctl start myapp@0.1.42.service  # start new version
systemctl stop myapp@0.1.23.service  # shutdown old processes

Is there any overhead of using dynamic parameters like the above, compared to a fixed set of unit names? Specifically, is there a resource the system allocates for new instance unit names? Will journald logs from dynamic instance units be compacted to the same size as if the logs came from one service?
systemctl start worker@{1..10}.service  # unit names do not change

Similar question: How to follow systemd journald logs for template units that come and go (i.e. socket-activated units)?
